# Gunicorn + Flask-Restful : High CPU usage while starting

Tags: python, cpu-usage, gunicorn, supervisord, flask-restful

I have a Flask-Restful App with a pretty standard server stack

- WSGI Server : Gunicorn
- Async worker class : Gevent / sync

When I start/restart my flask app via supervisorctl, the CPU load goes very high till the app is loaded. And it takes around 10-20 secs for the app to load.

I've tried running the app on the following instance configs

1. 8 core, 15 GB RAM
2. 2 core, 7.5 GB RAM

But on both of the instances, the behaviour is quite similar. The CPU usage rises drastically to ~35-40 %.

I'm not able to find the root cause of this load. Can there be any issue with Gunicorn combined with Flask-Restful?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you modify your question to include a list of other libraries that you are using? Usually CPU usage will spike if you're importing other libraries that do expensive initialization stuff.